# Insert an element to linked list with the help of recursion

Tags: recursion, linked-list

This Pascal code inserts a new element to a linked list with the help of "while loop":

```
    program linked_list;
type
    pointer_typ = ^record_2;
    record_2 = record
        data: integer;
        next: pointer_typ;
    end;
procedure Push_int(var p: pointer_typ; x: integer);
    var
        temp: pointer_typ;
    begin
        new(temp);
        temp^.data := x;
        temp^.next := p;
        p := temp
    end;
var
    first: pointer_typ;
    x: integer;
begin
    first := nil;
    while not Seekeof do begin
        read(x);
        Push_int(first, x)
    end;
end.
```

Can you help with making a procedure which inserts a new element to linked list but with the help of recursion (not with while loop)?
I tried and got wrong results (for example, the code below returns values in "queue order", but not in "stack order" as I'd like):

```
    program linked_list;
type
    pointer_typ = ^record_2;
    record_2 = record
        data: integer;
        next: pointer_typ;
    end;
procedure Push_int(var p: pointer_typ);
    var
        temp: pointer_typ;
        x: integer;
    begin
        read(x);
        new(temp);
        temp^.data := x;
        temp^.next := p;
        p := temp;
        if Seekeof then
            exit
        else
            Push_int(p^.next)
    end;
var
    first: pointer_typ;
begin
    first := nil;
    Push_int(first);
end.
```

Thank you.

Comment: It is always good to post a (small) [MCVE]. And tell us what you expect and what actually happens. That way, we can see if the problem is in the routine above or elsewhere, e.g. how and with what you call the procedure (is p the head or tail, etc.) For such code, I usually draw things on paper first, with arrows for the pointers and squares for the nodes.

Comment: Hope, this variant is clearer.

Comment: The first one looks better, but you are not adding to the end of the list, you are adding to the front. Find out why: do that thing with paper and pencil and soon you'll see the error. Note that you can change the pointers in p too. Also try to debug your program or perhaps add some temporary writelns to see what is being placed where exactly. Remove those writelns when you're finished. Don't forget that the next pointer of the last node should be nil. First do it as a while loop, then -- if it works -- change it to be recursive.

Comment: Recursion: check if p = nil. Then create a new node and point p to it. if p = first, you are finished. otherwise, add the new node to the end of p. if p was not nil, call `push_int(p^.next, x);`, which does the same for the next node (or nil). If p^.next is not nil, you haven't reached the end of the list yet, so you must recurse to examine the next node, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, this one works correct:

```
program linked_list;
type
    pointer_typ = ^record_2;
    record_2 = record
        data: integer;
        next: pointer_typ;
    end;
procedure Push_int(var p: pointer_typ; x: integer);
    var
        temp: pointer_typ;
    begin
        new(temp);
        temp^.data := x;
        temp^.next := p;
        p := temp;
        if Seekeof then
            exit
        else begin
            read(x);
            Push_int(p, x)
        end;
    end;
var
    first: pointer_typ;
    x: integer;
begin
    first := nil;
    read(x);
    Push_int(first, x)
end.
```